# Does logback-android support DBAppender?

Tags: android, logging, logback, appender

The android implementation of logback appears to be missing the DBAppender class.

Here's my relevant logback appender config, located in assets/logback.xml.

```
    <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://10.2.2.222:3306/logback</url>
            <user>username</user>
            <password>thepassword</password>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>
```

And gradle:

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
implementation 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:1.1.1-12'
```

and the resulting error in my logcat:

```
20:40:50,225 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction -
  Could not create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender].
    ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: 
  Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: 
  Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender
```

and

```
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: 
   Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
   Didn't find class "ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender"
```

Logback is properly working otherwise, if I comment out the database stuff and just have it log to a file, it instantiates correctly and generates text in the log file.

I've found examples of people using the DBAppender, but haven't found any that appear to be **android based**.

ps: I've also tried the other option, DataSourceConnectionSource (as opposed to the shown DriverManagerConnectionSource) but it actually uses the same appender, and so has the same error as a result. I also can't find any references to to DBAppender in the github files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logback-android` currently does not support `DBAppender`, and there are no firm plans to carry over that feature. The only database appender supported is [`SQLiteAppender`](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/wiki/Appender-Notes#sqliteappender).

It should be relatively simple to pull `DBAppender`'s relevant source from `logback` into its own library that could be used in `logback-android`. For a future major release, I plan on splitting out several built-in appenders in this way to minimize the library size.

Comment: Definitive answer from library author tony19, nice!